# Callback in backbone event handler

Tags: events, backbone.js, callback, marionette

How do I get the value of result (bold).

I am requesting a handler.

Handler is calling a function which in turn is making ajax call to the server.

I want to be able to be finish with ajax call and return the result accordingly.

In the below code whatever error or success 'result' is always false because the App.reqres is being returned before ajax call is finished.

How can I restructure my code?

In view

```
    resetPassword: function(event) {
        var ***result*** = App.reqres.request('reset_password', this.$email.val());
        if(!result){
            // If email is not registered
        }else{
           // send a link to reset password
        }
    },
```

Handler

```
   var API = {
        reset_password: function(email, callback) {
            var promise = // some ajax call to the server

            var result = false;

            $.when(promise).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                result = true;
            }).fail(function() {
                result = false;
            }).done(function(){
                return result;
            });
        }
    };

    App.reqres.setHandler("reset_password", function(email) {
        return API.reset_password(email);
    });
```

One Solution: ( Is there any better way ??)

```
    resetPassword: function(event) {

        var message = this.$message;
        **// the whole block is passed as callback**
        var callback = function(result) {
            if (!result) {
                message.html('Email is not registered.')
                message.removeClass('success');
                message.addClass('error');
            } else {
                message.html('A reset code and reset password link has been sent to this email.')
                message.removeClass('error');
                message.addClass('success');
            }
        }
        var result = App.reqres.request('reset_password', this.$email.val(), callback);

    }

    var API = {
        reset_password: function(email, callback) {
            var promise = promiseObject('resetPassword', {'email': email}, 'POST');

            $.when(promise).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               callback(true); **// pass the result in the callback function**
            }).fail(function() {
                callback(false); **// pass the result in the callback function**
            });
        }

    };

    App.reqres.setHandler("reset_password", function(email, callback) {
        return API.reset_password(email, callback);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply return the promise and then use your callbacks in your `resetPassword` method, like so:

```
resetPassword: function(event) {
    var message = this.$message;
    App.reqres.request('reset_password', this.$email.val())
      .then(function() {
        // send link to reset password
        message.html('A reset code and reset password link has been sent to this email.')
        message.removeClass('error');
        message.addClass('success');
      })
      .fail(function() {
        // If email is not registered
        message.html('Email is not registered.')
        message.removeClass('success');
        message.addClass('error');
      });
},
```

And then your request handler would look like this:

```
var API = {
    reset_password: function(email) {
        var promise = // some ajax call to the server

        return $.when(promise);
    }
};

App.reqres.setHandler("reset_password", function(email) {
    return API.reset_password(email);
});
```

Which makes sense since you're making an asynchronous. Passing the promise back to the method that cares makes handling it much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
        return $.when(promise).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            return true;
        }).fail(function() {
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: This way result is 'undefined'. Because all calls are returned before ajax call finished. Thanks for the books on Marionette btw :)

Comment: Oops, you're right... It seems you either needs to use a callback as you proposed, or return a promise and handle the return value where you call it. See https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/entities/contact.js#L72 (ignore `setTimeout`) and https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/show/show_controller.js#L11 Glad you liked the books !